# Celery callback inconsistent arguments

Tags: python, callback, celery

Writing a celery integration into Django and am confused about the celery's behavior when linking callbacks with mutable signatures. The idea is that `main_task` creates an object (e.g. a `flow`) which it passes its id to `task_one`. `task_one` accepts the argument via a mutable signature and prints the id created in `main_task`.

On completion of `task_one`, `alt_task` is called. So far so good. However, in `alt_task` a new object is created and that id is returned. I then want to have the new id passed along for the reminder of the chain. What is happening is that the first object's id is being passed along, whereas I want it to be replaced by the new object's.

```py
@shared_task()
def alt_task():
    flow = Flow.objects.create()
    return flow.id


@shared_task()
def task_one(flow_id):
    flow = Flow.objects.get(id=flow_id)
    print(flow.id)
    return flow.id


@shared_task()
def main_task(flow_id):
    flow = Flow.objects.create()
    ...
    task_one.apply_async(
        args=(flow.id,),
        link=(alt_task.si(), task_one.s(), ...),
        link_error=log_error.s()
    )

# prints
1
1

# what I want
1
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the why the above doesn't transfer the arguments linearly and if anyone knows fully, I'd happily set that as the correct answer. In the meantime, what I did to mitigate this was to separate the call into a celery group. The first entry in the group being the tasks that need the first flow object's id and a chain of tasks that use the id created in `alt_task`

```py
...
task_chain = (alt_task.si() | task_one.s() |  ...)
job = group([alt_task.si(flow.id), task_chain])
job.apply_async()


1
2
```